# Custom value using Cascading Parameter in ssrs /report builder

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder

I have scenario i have a dataset which is used for cascading parameter which is able to select multi select values . I need to display the selected values in the report . **So if all values are selected in parameters should display as  "ALL " , ELSE if any values selected should display as selected values in the report**

Note : parameters are cascading type . Assue data sets has more than one column

Answer (score 0):

In your header section, create a placeholder and use this in the expression:

```
=switch(Parameters!folder.Count = CountRows("your_dataset"),"Value (s): All",
    Parameters!folder.Count <> CountRows("your_dataset"), "Value (s): " + (JOIN(Parameters!folder.Label,", ")))
```

Replace **your_dataset** with the **dataset** used for your parameter. It will display "Value (s): All" when all values are selected, otherwise it will display the selected values separated by comma.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse . I tried but if you select all values it showing all the selected values not ALL .

Comment: Let me explain the case , based on parameter 1 parameter 2 gets filtered and on parameter 2 i am selecting multiple values and if select all values values ALL should appear else only how many values got selected only that values should displayed

Comment: I know you said you are using a dataset to populate parameter 2 and that is filtered by parameter 1. How is the dataset being filtered? I believe you need to be using the query to filter (ex. where column = @parameter1) instead of using the dataset filter tab.

Comment: I am using dataset filter tab.In dataset 2 I am adding required filter (i.e ) paramter 1. To get filter

Comment: My suggestion is to remove the filter on parameter 1 in the filter tab; add the filter to your query "where column = @parameter1"

Comment: hi, i have tried with the logic ALL is displayed for few selections only , for other selections i am getting the selected values instead of ALL .So where will the issue any idea ?

Comment: can you please include specific examples of what you mean? you have two parameters and it's difficult to figure out what you mean.